# Federate authentication between Azure Active Directory and Apigee Edge

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-active-directory, jwt, apigee

Let me try to explain my query using this diagram:

[image]

1. I have an existing APIGEE STS that issues a JWT after verifying the username and password. This STS has its own "**Generate-JWT**" policy defined with issuer, subject, audience, etc.
2. My Client App receives the JWT after successful authentication. This JWT is then passed to the existing NodeJS API that verifies the JWT issued by APIGEE STS and returns the data.

Now, I have to connect to another NodeJS API from my Client App to fetch the data. And, this is where I need some guidance.

1. This new NodeJS API is registered with AAD and already has the JWT verification (BearerStrategy) implemented using "**passport-azure-ad**".
2. The API is able to verify the tokens which are issued by AAD.

However, I also need to get my JWT verified (by NEW NodeJS API) that was issued by APIGEE STS.
I learned about the Federated Authentication between AAD and APIGEE and I tried setting it up. But nothing seems to work.

I always get this error:

> authentication failed due to: In Strategy.prototype.jwtVerify: We did
> not receive a token we know how to validate

I need guidance on this problem and the right way to approach towards such usecases.